# A way to recognise word in string vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to extract a code from a string based on its properties. Example 'M2.W1.SSE'. I am already splitting the string by words (codes) and I am examining the codes individually. But this is where Im stuck.

I am looking for a word that contains M as starting letter and contains 2 fulls tops. What would be the best way to do that? I can isolate the M by substring  but the 2 full stops is what Im having problems with. I can only do one full stop and that may capture other codes.

```
    Dim SplitCodes() As String = Split(StringOfCodes, " ")

    For Each code As String In SplitCodes
        If code.substring(0,1) = "M" andalso code.Contains(".") = True Then
            'Delete the code from the string
         End if
    Next
```

Comment: Why can't you say `code.Contains("..")`

Comment: Try to check if the string has dots after removing the first substring. if there are then do something and continue it like a loop maybe?

Comment: @Rahul code.contains("..") will never match as it the code looks like this 'M2.W1.SSE'

Comment: @ Ivan, Yes I could split each code in the loop by the full stops and that would give me the count. That would work, is there may be a better more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Can't you split again on `"."`?

Comment: is there may be a better more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of the string is equal to the length of the string -2 where full stop has been replaced with nothing:

```
If code.Substring(0, 1) = "M" And Len(Replace(code, ".", "")) = Len(code) - 2 Then
```

Here is a simple test I put together for it:

```
    Dim MyString As String
    MyString = "M2.W1.SSE"
    If MyString.Substring(0, 1) = "M" And Len(Replace(MyString, ".", "")) = Len(MyString) - 2 Then
        TextBox1.Text = MyString
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Didn't work!!"
    End If
```

The first part of the if triggered, then replacing the second full stop with a comma triggered the else

You can also use the split method to count the number of elements created:

```
    Dim MyString As String
    MyString = "M2.W1.SSE"
    If MyString.Substring(0, 1) = "M" And Len(Replace(MyString, ".", "")) = Len(MyString) - 2 Then
        TextBox1.Text = MyString
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Didn't work!!"
    End If
    If code.Substring(0, 1) = "M" And UBound(Split(MyString, ".")) = 2 Then '<-- Option base zero creates 3 elements with the upper one being index 2
        MsgBox("This method also works")
    Else
        MsgBox("This method doesn't work")
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you , I personally prefer the second option for some reason.

Comment: Personally so do I, I like the split function and I use it a lot for these sorts of things :). Some people may find it harder to understand so the other option is there in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used a similar method that references a function. I could conceivably use the above suggested code to replace the count characters function.

```
     If code.Substring(0, 1) = "M" AndAlso CountCharacters(code, ".") = 2 Then 
            'Found
     Else
            'Not found
     End If


     Public Function CountCharacters(ByVal sString As String, ByVal ch As Char) As Integer
            Dim cnt As Integer = 0
            For Each c As Char In sString
                If c = ch Then cnt += 1
            Next
            Return cnt
        End Function
```

Comment: Why would you choose to loop instead if split in your function? Split would be much more efficient

Comment: Re reading the code you have literally chosen the most inefficient way polling char by char